# Cannot boot ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04

So I got this used laptop that supposedly has both windows 8.1 and ubuntu 16.04 installed.
I am not entirely sure what has happened because I got this from my brother but he says while trying to install ubuntu, he got a message about not overwr'iting on the windows partition, which he ofc did.
Now the only way to get a little bit of ubuntu, is to stick a usb stick in it and boot from there. I have tried boot repair, did not work. I have turned off uefi and reaches grub rescue but do not knwo what to do from here.
I hope you guys can help..

Regards

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Is there data on the laptop that you need to preserve? If not, i'd say format the HDD and reinstall both OS'es from scratch.